# Metasploit Plugin not interacting with Meterpreter Client

Tags: metasploit, ruby, meterpreter

I'm developing a plugin to automate some post exploitation tasks. Two days ago all methods that interact with the client (from the client_core and stdapi) simply don't return anything, like if in a while(true) loop.
Although when I'm in irb mode with the same session everything works fine.
I've tried changing the victim machine and created a dummy plugin, which presented the same problem.
What could it be?
This is the dummy code:

```
module Msf

class Plugin::Automigrate < Msf::Plugin

include Msf::SessionEvent

def initialize(framework, opts)
    super
    self.framework.events.add_session_subscriber(self)

end

def on_session_open(session)
    print_status("Session Opened")
    print_status(session.core.use("sniffer"))
    if(session.core.use("stdapi"))
        print_good("stdapi loaded")
    end
    print_status("#{session.sys}")
    puts "#{session.sys}"
    t = session.sys.config.getuid
    print_good("#{t}")

end

def name
    "AutoMigrate"   
end

end
```

And the only thing it returns is the "Session Opened" status.

Comment: I'm not sure how we could possibly be able to answer your question. At best, this is a programming question and you might get traction on SO if tagged as `ruby`.

Comment: Wait - so the code worked 2 days ago, and now it's not? Did you update MSF?

Comment: No, I haven't. What is puzzling me is the fact the all the above commands work fine through irb on the same meterpreter session.

Comment: I've also restored a snapshot of my kali linux and ran the plugin there, same problem presented. So I think it's something wrong on my code.

Comment: I've also tested a plugin that ships with metasploit (session_tagger), and is presenting the same problem.

Comment: ok - then this is either a question for the metasploit community or StackOVerflow.